# Exim lsearch lookup in multiple files at the same time

Tags: exim

I need to have Exim go through multiple files in an lsearch lookup, stopping when the first match is found.

To be more concrete, I have `/etc/exim/plain1` and `/etc/exim/plain2` which contain authenticator data.

My current solution works with only one file:

```
PLAIN:
  driver = plaintext
  client_send = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain1}}
```

How can I extend this to also check `/etc/exim/plain2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it by wrapping one `lookup` into another like this:

```
  client_send = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain1}{$value}\
               {${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain2}}}}
```

This can be extended to more lookups by wrapping further:

```
  client_send = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain1}{$value}\
               {${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain2}{$value}\
               {${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain3}}}}}
```

It would have been nice though, if `lsearch` could accept a *list* of files and lookup in them sequentially..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OR** condition:

```
client_send = ${or {lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain1}} \
                   {lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/plain2}} }
```

`Exim` evaluate conditions from left to right until current condition yield `true` and its result returned. If no true subconditions found then whole condition yield `false` and an empty result returned.

Refer to the chapter 11.8 of the `exim's` specification.

Comment: This does not work - `${or` currently works only inside an `${if`.